# Null check operator used on a null value error on flutter Drag&Drop

Tags: flutter, dart, drag-and-drop

Here is the code for a page that is supposed to manage drag and drop functionality for a range of food items that should be dragged and dropped to some other items (nearly 20 items into 6 groups). I've managed to write these so far.

here is the piece of code I wrote:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FoodDragAndDropPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FoodDragAndDropPageState createState() => _FoodDragAndDropPageState();
}

class _FoodDragAndDropPageState extends State<FoodDragAndDropPage> {
  final scoreKeeper = ScoreKeeper();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Food Grouping Game'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FoodGroupTarget(
            name: 'Fruits',
            group: FoodGroup.fruit,
            scoreKeeper: scoreKeeper,
          ),
          FoodGroupTarget(
            name: 'Vegetables',
            group: FoodGroup.vegetable, scoreKeeper: scoreKeeper,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FoodItemsGrid(
              onDragCompleted: _checkFoodItem,
            ),
          ),
          ScorePanel(scoreKeeper: scoreKeeper),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _checkFoodItem(FoodItem foodItem, FoodGroup targetGroup) {
    if (foodItem.group == targetGroup) {
      // Food item dragged to correct group
      scoreKeeper.incrementScore();
    } else {
      // Food item dragged to wrong group
      scoreKeeper.decrementScore();
    }

    if (scoreKeeper.isStageComplete()) {
      // Handle stage complete
      _showStageCompleteOverlay();
    }
  }

  void _showStageCompleteOverlay() {
    // Overlay to handle stage completion
  }
}

class ScoreKeeper {
  int score = 0;
  int maxPossibleScore = 20;

  void incrementScore() {
    score++;
  }

  void decrementScore() {
    score--;
  }

  bool isStageComplete() {
    return score >= maxPossibleScore;
  }
}

class ScorePanel extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScoreKeeper scoreKeeper;

  ScorePanel({required this.scoreKeeper});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Score: ${scoreKeeper.score}'),
          Text('Target: ${scoreKeeper.maxPossibleScore}'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FoodItemsGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(FoodItem, FoodGroup) onDragCompleted;

  FoodItemsGrid({required this.onDragCompleted});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      children: [
        FoodItem(
          name: 'Apple',
          group: FoodGroup.fruit,
          onDragCompleted: onDragCompleted,
        ),
        FoodItem(
          name: 'Broccoli',
          group: FoodGroup.vegetable,
          onDragCompleted: onDragCompleted,
        ),
        //...other food items
      ],
    );
  }
}

enum FoodGroup {
  fruit,
  vegetable,
  //...other groups
}

class FoodItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final FoodGroup group;
  final Function(FoodItem, FoodGroup) onDragCompleted;

  FoodItem({
    required this.name,
    required this.group,
    required this.onDragCompleted,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Draggable(
      feedback: Container(color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.5)),
      onDragCompleted: () {
        // Determine target group and call callback
        // Find enclosing FoodGroupTarget
        final target = context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<FoodGroupTarget>();

        if (target != null) {
          onDragCompleted(this, target.group);
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Text(name),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FoodGroupTarget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final FoodGroup group;
  final ScoreKeeper scoreKeeper;

  FoodGroupTarget({
    required this.name,
    required this.group,
    required this.scoreKeeper,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DragTarget(
      builder: (context, candidates, rejected) {
        return Container(
          width: 150,
          height: 150,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text(name),
        );
      },
        onAccept: (FoodItem? foodItem) {
          // Check if food item is not null
          if (foodItem != null) {
            // Check if food item group matches target group
            if (foodItem.group == this.group) {
              // Correct match, update score
              scoreKeeper.incrementScore();
            } else {
              // Incorrect group, update score
              scoreKeeper.decrementScore();
            }
          }
        },
    );
  }
}
```

but When I drag the item (e.g. Apple) I get this null check operator error:

======== Exception caught by gesture library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown while routing a pointer event:
Null check operator used on a null value

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _DragTargetState.didDrop (package:flutter/src/widgets/drag_target.dart:719:38)
#1      _DragAvatar.finishDrag (package:flutter/src/widgets/drag_target.dart:888:22)
#2      _DragAvatar.end (package:flutter/src/widgets/drag_target.dart:801:5)
#3      MultiDragPointerState._up (package:flutter/src/gestures/multidrag.dart:158:14)
#4      MultiDragGestureRecognizer._handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/multidrag.dart:266:13)
#5      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:98:12)
#6      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes. (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:143:9)
#7      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:625:13)
#8      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes
...

Everything seemed to be correct. I assumed the problem was with the OnAccepts callback and modified it a couple of times but it didn't work either. Can somebody please tell me, What am I getting wrong here?!

Comment: add `data: this,` to the `Draggable`

Comment: @Ivo Thanks a lot! I totally missed that one!